# Facebook like counter displaying site likes not article level likes

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, zend-framework, twitter

I've added the Facebook like counter along with the other standard social media sharing options. They all work as expected, the individual articles count likes for just that article and the home page shows total likes for the site.

We're running into issues on our list pages. The list pages consist of multiple pages with one introduction page. The interior pages of the list show the correct number of likes/shares for that list but the introduction page is displaying the total likes for the site, not for that list.

Any idea what could be happening here? I thought it might have to do with the URL structuring but there is no clear variance. Here is what they look like:

List introduction:
- www.mysite.com/categorytitle/thelisttitle/
List page:
- www.mysite.com/categorytitle/thelisttitle/listitem1

Here is what i'm using to embed everything:

```
    <div id="social-share">
        <div class="share_contain">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>(function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            </script>
            <fb:like href="http://mysite.com/<?= $this->uri ?>" send="false" width="50" layout="button_count" show_faces="false"></fb:like>         </div>
        <div class="share_contain">
            <a href="http://mysite.com/<?= $this->uri ?>" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="medium">Tweet</a>
            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
        </div>
        <div class="share_contain">
            <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
            <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium"></div>
            <!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
              (function() {
                var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
              })();
            </script>

        </div>
       </div>
```

**UPDATE**

If anyone ever runs into a similar issue with Facebook, Google +1 or Twitter, make sure your conical links have the correct url.

Comment: How are you displaying the like buttons? What's the code you're using?

Comment: I'm using the standard twitter, google plus & the HTML5 facebook code.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Tomer I've updated my question with the source i'm using to generate everything.

Comment: I have this exact same problem at my side. http://www.thinkingmedia.ca, I have both a Like button for a page and also a "Find Us On Facebook" for liking our company page on Facebook. When I remove the "Find Us On Facebook" from the sidebar, then the like button works correctly. But both don't play well together. Is this the same in your case?

Comment: Not exactly, we only have the Facebook like, google +1, and tweet buttons and just one instance of them. The only time it doesn't work correctly is when we're on an introduction page for the lists. For instance, the internal list pages show 5 likes but the introduction page for the list page shows 1K likes which isn't actually for the list but for the whole site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you place the like button for each item? does any item page has its own like button? or do you place several like buttons in the introduction page for each item (and for the list)?Anyway, a good tool to check things out is the facebook debug tool (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), if I understood you correctly, it might be wrong item url or wrong og meta tag (especially look at the og:url meta tag).

Comment: I'm feeding the FB Like with a dynamic URL which creates a unique like button instance for each page. <fb:like href="http://mysite.com/<?= $this->uri ?>" send="false" width="50" layout="button_count" show_faces="false"></fb:like>

Comment: This wasn't really the answer but it helped me find the answer. Thanks so much Naama!